# What gems does Lily Roth not sell?

Tags: path-of-exile

Assume one is already at the atlas (past epilogue).

What gems does Lily Roth (in act 6, I think) not sell and where to find them?

Excluding corrupted and quality gems because those won't be sold by NPC anyway, and the ones listed below, is there any other?

- Empower Support
- Enhance Support
- Enlighten Support
- Portal
- Block Chance Reduction Support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that's the [correct list](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_drop-only_gems). The only thing I would add to that list are the [Vaal gems.](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Vaal_skill)]

Please also note that [Awakened Gems](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Awakened_Support_Skill_Gems) are not available - those drop from the new Atlas mechanic. (thanks to Tylor for update)

Comment: `Excluding corrupted` <---- All Vaal gems are corrupted.

Comment: This list does not include awakened gems, added with Patch 3.9, the Metamorph league, as of December 13th, 2019.

Comment: @Tylor thanks, i added that to my answer and gave you credit ;)